# Is the NASA Space-Shuttle the object with most reproductions in LEGO sets?

Tags: history

Even within the last twenty years, there have been a large number of LEGO reproductions of NASA's Space Shuttle, e.g.

- [31117 Space Shuttle Adventure​](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/31117)
- [31091 Shuttle Transporter](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/31091)
- [10283 NASA Space Shuttle Discovery](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/10283)
- [7470 Space Shuttle Discovery](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/7470)
- [31066 Space Shuttle Explorer](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/31066)
- [3367 Space Shuttle](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/3367)
- [31134 Space Shuttle](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/31134)

There have also been Space-Shuttles made in Duplo ([10944 Space Shuttle Mission](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/10944) ), sets with shuttle-like craft which may or may not be the shuttle ([60080 Spaceport](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/60080) ), and actual space-shuttles included in other sets (e.g. [21312 Women of NASA](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/21312) ).

This got me to thinking that perhaps the Space Shuttle may be the object(s) which have been most reproduced in LEGO, but then thinking more logically it is more likely to be something more generic like a police-car (where I can see at least five sets that consist of *just a police-car* on the first page when searching for instructions on the LEGO website).

**Does anyone know what object (or building, character, etc.) has been reproduced in as many independent LEGO sets as possible?**

Comment: You probably want to define what you mean by object. Does it have to be something that exists in real life? Also, are we only including sets where this object is the main feature?

Comment: I don't want to impose too many conditions on the question, since I already think it will be difficult to answer. So, my answers to your questions would be: "Both real and fictional objects are welcome.", and "Whatever makes it easiest to answer the question".

Comment: Is a car tire an "object"?

Comment: I assume the object has to consist of multiple parts, and single parts don't count ? Otherwise a "brick" object would yield many different sizes and shapes of brick parts. Any other size/type constraints ? The line has to be drawn somewhere, otherwise objects like "rock" or "wall" or "undercarriage" would easily win.

Comment: Additionally, the specificity of the object needs to be defined, otherwise "space craft" easily wins over "space shuttle".

Comment: @NeilTarrant I don’t really understand you not wanting to impose too many conditions, you currently don’t have any. As others have pointed out, there are many uninteresting trivial answers which could be avoided with some kind of specification

Answer (score 2):

Without a more precise definition of what you are looking for it is very difficult to say what has been done most. For instance, a "building" is something you can find in several thousand sets of Lego.

So, if we narrow it down and say we only consider something which can be identified as the same, the highest reproductions I can find is the Millennium Falcon from Star Wars.

This varies from a small polybag set to *the* Millenium Falcon with over 7500 bricks

According to [Brick Land](https://www.thebrickland.com/lego-millennium-falcon-review/) there have been 25 reproductions so far.